# Getting message id from message.content djs

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I was working on webhook discord bot and just asking is there a way to return value of messageid id. example:

```js
if(message.content === "msgid"){
  const messageid = 
  message.channel.send(`Your message id is ${messageid}`)
}
```

any help, I will appreciate it

Comment: `Message.id`? This should work...

Comment: Its actually work! I hope this comment is answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`Message.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=id)

```js
const messageid = message.id
```